# Is there any disadvantage in Mixing Excercises?

Tags: exercise

I done two sets of  **SEATED OVERHEAD DUMBBELL EXTENSION**....

Now before completing third set, can i do one set of **Incline Barbell Triceps Extension**....

than again doing **third set** of SEATED OVERHEAD DUMBBELL EXTENSION....

**example** :

1. 2 sets of SEATED OVERHEAD DUMBBELL EXTENSION
2. 1 set of Incline Barbell Triceps Extension
3. 1 set of SEATED OVERHEAD DUMBBELL EXTENSION
4. 2 sets of Incline Barbell Triceps Extension

Also if i do 6 type of triceps excercises [ say excercises names as a, b ,c , d, e , f ] , is i need to follow in orderwise ?

or is it fine to follow random order [ **d , b , f, c , e, a** ] but at the end of day, i will complete all 6 excercises ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No matter how many different exercise variations you select from, it's all just six sets of tricep extensions. These are isolation exercises - they only involve one muscle, so there really isn't going to be any significant difference imposed by modifying the form of external resistance.

It's not going to matter whether three of those sets are with dumbbells and three with a barbell, or if you substituted some with cable pulldowns. The order is also unlikely to matter, since they're all such similar movements.

Adding additional variations is just going to make it harder to track how much weight you need for each variant.